# Efficiently selecting from a large table using floor() in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables: One with squares with columns x and y over the natural numbers, and another with points on this grid created by the first table. Example schema:

`Grid Table`

```
id  | x | y
------------  
123 | 1 | 1  
234 | 1 | 2
345 | 2 | 1   
456 | 2 | 2
```

Then, the `points table`:

```
id |   x  |  y  
----------------
12 | 1.23 | 1.23
23 | 2.89 | 1.55
```

Currently, using this query:

```
SELECT g.* FROM grid as g, points as p  
WHERE p.id=23 AND floor(p.x)=g.x AND floor(p.y)=g.y;
```

I get the expected result, which is the grid square in which the point with id `23` resides (grid with id `345`); However, when the table `grid` has 10,000,000 rows (the current situation I'm in), this query is *incredibly* slow, i.e. on the order of a few seconds.

I've found a workaround for this, but it's ugly:

```
SELECT g.* FROM grid as g, points as p  
WHERE p.id=23 AND (p.x-.5)::integer=g.x AND (p.y-.5)::integer=g.y;
```

I get the expected result again, and in 11ms, but this feels hacky. Are there cleaner ways to do this? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a CTE, as it is evaluated once only.

```
WITH p2 AS (select floor(p.x) x, 
                   floor(p.y) y 
            from points  p 
            where p.id=23)
SELECT  g.* 
FROM grid g
INNER JOIN  p2
ON p2.x=g.x and p2.y=g.y
```